# How can I get rid of 'floating point exception' in this C code?

Tags: c, exception

This piece of code is giving 'signal: floating point exception (core dumped)' error.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fact(int n);
int comb(int x, int y);
int greater(int x, int y);

int main() {
    int count = 0;
    for (int n = 1; n <= 100; n++) {
        for (int r = 0; r <= n; r++) {
            if (greater(n, r)) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", count);
    return 0;
}

int fact(int n) {
    if (n == 0 || n == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    return n * fact(n - 1);
}

int comb(int x, int y) {
    return fact(x) / (fact(x - y) * fact(y));
}

int greater(int x, int y) {
    if (comb(x, y) > 1000000) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The 'comb' function, which returns the combination of two numbers, is always supposed to return an integer. I also don't think I'm dividing by zero anywhere because I already added the condition that fact(0) returns 1. What could be the cause and how to fix it?

Comment: 100! will be too large to fit in `int`. You should use multiple-precision arithmetic.

Comment: Generic suggestion: Step though your program with a debugger, it will precisely tell you where the problem is.

Comment: don't divide by 0?

Comment: you can consider using `double` rather than `int`. It has a dynamic range that may suit your purpose however you will lose some accuracy what may not be relevant for your needs.

Answer (score 2):

The “floating point exception” is a [legacy of old computer hardware and software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60127747/why-was-sigfpe-used-for-integer-arithmetic-exceptions). What it actually indicates in this case is division by zero.

Division by zero occurs because the numbers you are using exceed the range representable in `int`. Some of the overflows produce zero as a result, and then `fact(x) / (fact(x - y) * fact(y))` divides by zero.

You will not be able to compute `comb(100, 50)` using just ordinary `int` arithmetic. You will need to write or use multiprecision software or will need to approximate the value using floating-point arithmetic.